# Puzzled by TensorFlow nn.in_top_k output

Tags: tensorflow

I modified [tensorflow convnet tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.html)
to train just two classes.

Then I evaluated the model using [cifar10_eval.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.11/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_eval.py)

I tried to understand the output of [tf.nn.in_top_k](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/nn.html#in_top_k)

L128    top_k_op = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, labels, 1)

which is printed out as:

in_top_k output:::
`[array([ True, False,  True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)]`

while the true labels(two classes, 10 images) are:::
`[0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0]`

and the logits are:::

```
[[ 1.45472026 -1.46666598]
 [-1.0181191   1.03441548]
 [-1.02658665  1.04306769]
 [-1.19205511  1.21065331]
 [-1.22167087  1.24064851]
 [-0.89583808  0.91119087]
 [-0.17517655  0.18206072]
 [-0.09379113  0.09957675]
 [-1.05578279  1.07254183]
 [ 0.73048806 -0.73411369] ]
```

Question: Why the second and fourth `nn.in_top_k()` output are `False` instead of `True`?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

It shouldn't happen.

I evaluated the example you gave and got:

```
In [6]: top_k_op = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, labels, 1)

In [7]: top_k_op.eval()
Out[7]: array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

By the way, you can substitute `in_top_k(A, B, 1)` by a simple `argmax`:

```
In [14]: tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, 1), labels, tf.int64).eval()
Out[14]: array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```